# pivot table cash flow

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I have a table with my cash flow:

Cash flow table:
[image: cash flow table]

Where: 
Data → Transaction date (Brazilian time DD-MM-YY)
Type →  SAIDA = Cash outflow and ENTRADA=cash inflow

What I need is to know each day balance value like that:

Expected result:

[image: Expected result]

To do that I'd have to grab the last occurrence of each day buy I'm not managing to that.

I've already tried to use pivot table but unsuccessfully. As you can see below, using pivot table I receive more than one date per balance.

[image: Pivot table showing more than one date for balance]

Pivot table set up:

[image: Pivot table set up]

Comment: Your desired results suggestY you'd want Min not Max and group by date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add a helper index column counting up.
2. Sort your list on the index column from high to low, so that the most recent transaction is on the top
3. Select your full table and use the `remove duplicates` option and only select your date column.

This will remove all duplicate dates and keeps rows with the last transaction of every date.

Comment: In number 1 you mean the table should be like that:
  
    (2.902,27 01/07/19 1)
    (2.902,47 01/07/19 2)
    (2.878,59 02/07/19 3)

Comment: Exactly, this helps you to sort your table from new to old.

Comment: Perfect. Tks very much!! Now I'm gonna discover how can I add that helper field automatically on Pivo table. Tks